# How to define a matrix by vectorization (without for loop) in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to define an NxN matrix A, whose element `A(i,j)` is `sin(i^2 + j)`.

In MATLAB, I can quickly define this matrix by employing vectorization.

```matlab
N = 2000;
ii = 1:N;
A = sin(ii.^2 + ii');
```

How to achieve this in Python? Right now, I am using for loops, which are slow.

```py
import numpy
N = 2000;
A = numpy.empty((N, N));
for i in range(1,N+1): 
    for j in range(1,N+1): 
        A[i-1][j-1] = numpy.sin(j + numpy.power(i, 2.))
```

Comment: `ii = np.arange(1, N + 1)` and `np.sin(ii ** 2 + ii[:, None])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things you can do in MATLAB have exact translations in numpy. [Here's a handy cheat-sheet](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

```
N = 2000 # remains unchanged
ii = np.arange(1, N+1)  # In the cheat-sheet section Linear Algebra Equivalents
```

Now, there's a slight difference. In MATLAB, everything is treated as a matrix, so a 1-dimensional array is just a `1xN` matrix, so transposing it is done just like any other matrix. In numpy, 1-dimensional arrays can't be transposed, so let's add a dummy dimension to `ii`:

```
ii = ii[None, :]
```

Now, `ii` is a `1xN` matrix, so we can get `A` as:

```
A = np.sin(ii**2 + ii.T);
```

Numpy takes care of broadcasting the shapes `(1, N)` and `(N, 1)` and gives you a result that is `(N, N)`

<sup>Note that `a'` in MATLAB is the *conjugate* transpose, which would be `a.conj().T` in numpy, but since these are all real numbers it makes no difference</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the use of `numpy` which allows for vectorization of arrays and array-like operations. I'm sure this can be reduced in size, but we can create an array in `x` and `y` before making a grid out of these points. We then apply the entire grid to the function `A=sin(i**2+j)`. We then get (I assume `ii'` is the same as the transpose of `ii`?)

```
import numpy as np # Import library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # To visualize
N = 2000 # NxN 
x = np.linspace(0,1,N)*np.pi #Define two arrays of length N
y = np.linspace(0,1,N)*np.pi

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y) #Create a NxN grid with arrays

A = np.sin(X**2+Y) # Apply grid to function

plt.imshow(A.T, origin='lower', aspect='auto') #Show that it has worked
plt.show()
```

which gives (updated to match your result in the range `[0,pi]`)

[image: result]